# Font scaling, variables, calculations in LaTeX

Tags: latex

I'm currently writing my CV and I'm running out of space. I wish to change the font in the whole CV template, but I want to do it proportionally. For example, some headings are 12pt, subheadings are 11pt. I want to be able to change them to 0.9 * 12 pt, 0.9 * 11 pt, aka to scale them accordingly. I want to change

```
\fontsize{12pt}{1em}
```

to

```
\fontsize{(0.9 * 12)pt}{1em}
```

, where \fontsize is a command from anyfontsize package.

But I end up with weird results and lots of logs/mistakes. Is there a way to ensure that '*' will produce a number, like in "regular" programming languages?

Other things I've tried include:

```
\newcommand{\myfont}[2]{\fontsize{0.9*#1pt}{0.9*#2}em}
\myfont{12}{1}
```

But it doesn't work the way I expect it to. I also tried adding brackets () and making a new command `\newcommand{\mymultiply}[2]{#1*#2}`

Is there an elegant and neat way to do this? Is there a "regular" way in LaTeX of doing actual calculations, or should I avoid this approach? Thanks in advance!

Comment: The regular LaTeX way is not not use hard coded font sizes but font commands like `\small`, `\Large` etc. If you then decide you want the font smaller or larger, you would change the argument of the documentclass, e.g. `\documentclass[10pt]{article}` instead of `\documentclass[11pt]{article}` and all fonts would scale automatically.

Comment: That said, you need to be careful with mixing font depended and independent units. `pt` is independent of the font, `em` depends on the font, scaling them both with the same factor will give a mess.

Answer (score 0):

3 possible approaches:

- I would avoid using hard coded font sizes altogether. If you instead us font commands like `\smaller` or `\larger` you can simply change the overall size with documentclass options like `10pt` or `12pt` and all the fonts in the document will scale, including sections etc.
- if you store your base fontsize in a length, you could use `\dimexpr` to make the calculations
- if for whatever reason you don't want to create a new length, you use an expl3 command to do the calculations

---

```
\documentclass[
%10pt
12pt
]{article}  

\usepackage{anyfontsize}

\ExplSyntaxOn
  \cs_new_eq:NN \fpeval \fp_eval:n
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}  

\section{section}

section

\newlength{\foo}
\setlength{\foo}{12pt}
\fontsize{\dimexpr.9\foo\relax}{\dimexpr1.08\foo \relax}\selectfont

test

\fontsize{\dimexpr\fpeval{.9*12}pt\relax}{\dimexpr\fpeval{.9*1.2*12}pt\relax}\selectfont

test

\end{document}
```